# How can i test custom fetch hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am struggling with an issue with the custom fetch hook.Simply i am trying to test my fetch hook if the data already fetched the hook needs to get data from cache instead of api.

The test case fails and looks like caching mechanism not working, but if i try on the browser with manual prop change caching mechanism works properly.

[image]

```
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
```

```
const renderList = (filterParams = testFilterParamsList[0]) =>
    render(<List filterParams={filterParams} />);

it("should re-render without fetch", async () => {
    const { rerender } = renderList(testFilterParamsList[0]);
    rerender(<List filterParams={testFilterParamsList[1]} />);
    expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

// useFetch.js

```
import {useEffect, useReducer} from "react";

const cache = {};

const FETCH_REQUEST = "FETCH_REQUEST";
const FETCH_SUCCESS = "FETCH_SUCCESS";
const FETCH_ERROR = "FETCH_SUCCESS";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isPending: false,
    error: null,
    data: [],
};

const useFetch = ({url, filterOptions}) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case FETCH_REQUEST:return {...INITIAL_STATE, isPending: true};
            case FETCH_SUCCESS: return {...INITIAL_STATE, isPending: false, data: action.payload};
            case FETCH_ERROR: return {...INITIAL_STATE, isPending: false, error: action.payload};
            default: return state;
        }
    }, INITIAL_STATE);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            dispatch({type: FETCH_REQUEST});
            if (cache[url]) {
                const data = cache[url];
                dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: data});
            } else {
                try {
                    const response = await window.fetch(url);
                    let data = await response.json();
                    cache[url] = data
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: data});
                } catch (err) {
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: err});
                }
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [filterOptions, url]);

    return state;
};

export default useFetch;
```

// List.js

```
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

export const RocketsList = ({ filterParams }) => {
  const { isPending, error, data } = useFetch({
    url: "https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/past",
    name:filterParams.name,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      Doesn't matter 
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you just place a console.log in your `useEffect` and check if it really gets called twice on mount?

Comment: Yes on the browser it appears just once, but with the test (with rerender) it appears two times. On the test case, with rerender props changing so useEffect is dependent on changed props.

Comment: But in the tests you are mounting the component (render) and then re-rendering (rerender). So I guess this is expected behavior? To have it called two times, right?

Comment: Unfortunately when the filter props keep the same it shouldn't fetch because cache[url] already full-filled.